# Removing preprocessing instructions from an XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml

How can i remove preprocessing instructions from an XML in a greener way? suppose that I have this xml in a `string` variable (which is a property of a class),I wanted to write it as value of another xml node,How can i achieve it in a cleaner way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<bookstore> 
  <book genre="autobiography">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

You help would be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can load it in an XmlDocument: FirstChild returns the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` node, and `NextSibling` returns the rest.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlNode node = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling;
```

Edit: Your xml looks a lot like the example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea193ac.aspx) for XPathNavigator.Select. Have you tried using that?

Edit2: You can get the name of the top level element using:

```
string topLevelNode = doc.DocumentElement.Name;
```

Comment: I cannot be sure that there will be only one preprocessing instruction in the xml , there may be more than 1 or may be none at all. So How can I approach this scenario?

Comment: Will you always have <bookstore> or might that be different, too?

Comment: Yeah that could be different as well. its like diffrent xml will be coming .

Comment: Actually I just post it as an  example only, my XMLs would be different.I wanted to know How I should approach the problem

Comment: Edited the answer to include a way to get the top level element name (bookstore in your example). Then you can use that with XPathNavigator.Select.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It will load the text to `XmlDocument` object first

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlAsText);
```

Then you can get the `OutherXml` using below:

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
```